# how to make angular mgl-timeline-entry 's start expanded

Tags: angular, angular-components, expand

I've found some trouble trying to expand a `mgl-timeline-entry` from the beginning, I found some options  like `toggle`, `alternate`, `focusOnOpen` and `side` but none seems to be useful for what I need.

How do I do this?

My code here:

```
<mgl-timeline  [alternate]="alternate" [side]="side" [toggle]="toggle" [mobileWidthThreshold]="2440">
  <mgl-timeline-entry #timelineComponent *ngFor="let event of incidentEvents; let i = index">
    <mgl-timeline-entry-header>
      <div translate>
        incidents.details.card.incident.event
        <span>{{ event.event_type }}</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="event.is_internal">
        <span translate>incidents.details.card.event.internal</span>
      </div>
    </mgl-timeline-entry-header>
    <mgl-timeline-entry-content style="display: block">
      <div>
        <div>
          <span class="font-bold" translate>incidents.details.card.incident.comments</span>
          <span>{{ event.description }}</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="font-bold" translate>incidents.details.card.incident.createdDate</span>
          <span>{{ event.incident_date }}</span>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="event.attachment">
          <div class="font-bold" translate>incidents.details.card.incident.attachments</div>
          <div class="attachment-event" *ngFor="let attach of event.attachment" (click)="download(attach)">{{ attach }}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mgl-timeline-entry-content>
    <mgl-timeline-entry-dot [size]="size" class="timeline-dot"></mgl-timeline-entry-dot>
    <mgl-timeline-entry-side>{{ timeSince(event.date_event) }} <span> ago</span></mgl-timeline-entry-side>
  </mgl-timeline-entry>
</mgl-timeline>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented this in my app, and bumped into the same problem.

I also could not find any useful property/ method to set 'expanded' as 'true'. I figured out a workaround (not the cleanest).

Using the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook, I added a method "expand()"

```
  expand() {
    let elem = document.getElementById('entry0');
    let evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      view: window
    });

    elem.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
```

My entries in my case are part of an ngFor loop, I assigned an 'id' to each header. Use could apply this to the dot instead, both would work.

```
<mgl-timeline-entry-header id="{{ 'entry' + i }}" class="header"
    (click)="onHeaderClick($event)">{{entry.date}} - {{entry.header}}</mgl-timeline-entry-header>
```

The idea is, after the entries load, you are instructing to programatically "Click" on each header/ dot.

I am not a big fan of document.getElementById, a similar solution could be implemented with ViewChild / ViewChildren.

Or use:

```
  @ViewChildren("header", { read: ElementRef }) private headers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  expandHeaders() {
    this.headers.forEach((header) => {
       header.nativeElement.click() });
  }

<mgl-timeline-entry-header #header class="header"
    (click)="onHeaderClick($event)">{{entry.date}} - {{entry.header}}</mgl-timeline-entry-header>
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you found a better solution / ideas.

Comment: great idea, thank you so much for sharing! Btw, you can just use document.getElementById() if you only want to open a specific header :) No need for @ViewChildren